# VueJS: Data of axios call

Tags: vue.js, axios

I built a vueJS component, that does an axios request when mounted. I want to populate different input fields with the response data.

```
mounted: function(){ 
      this.$root.$on('getmydata',(ID) => {
        this.ID= ID;
        axios.get('/edit/'+ID).then(response => this.details= response.data);
          this.InputField1 = this.details.mytext;
      });
```

But this way *this.InputField1* will be '*undefined*' (console.log). But if I do it like this:

```
axios.get('/edit/'+ID).then(response => this.InputField1= response.data.mytext);
```

the data is there (populated in the field).

**My Question:** I want to populate multiple fields with the response data. How can I use the response.data outside of axios.get().then(..)?

Comment: *How can I use the response.data outside of axios.get().then(..)?* - you can't.

Comment: Thanks @estus-flask that brought me to the solution.